# one frame containing different forms

Tags: html, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a website where I have to perform some operations inside iframes, so far I am able to switch to the frame and perform operations on the first page. But as soon as it navigates to the second page it doesn't work. I tried to check if there are more than one iframes, but there is only one.

On the first page, it shows the following as seen int the image:

[image]

On the second navigated page:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the HTML code of iframe:

[image]

In both the cases, the iframe is common but the description given is different, I am not able to identify the problem as per why it is not selecting the element.

can anybody give suggestion as per why this has occurred and what should I do to make it work fine?

This is the code which i have written for  first two pages

```
// page1//select the particular size
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)", "");
WebElement wi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'" + size + "')]/input[@type='radio']"));
if (wi.isDisplayed())
{
    System.out.println("displayed");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'" + size + "')]/input[@type='radio']")).click();
}
else
{
    System.out.println(" not displayed");
}
// get started
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@src,'get-started')]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Actions act = new Actions(driver);
// select a theme
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(" currently switching");
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/iframe[@id='mainFrame']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
System.out.println("switching done");
String url1 = "http://www.photojaanic.sg";
if (url.equals(url1))
{
    int sg = 20;

    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@class='div_img']/img[@src='http://services.nvi.co.in/themes/" + sg + "/3/" + themename + "/CF.jpg']"))
            .click();
}
else
{
    int in = 19;

    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@class='div_img']/img[@src='http://services.nvi.co.in/themes/" + in + "/3/" + themename + "/CF.jpg']")))
            .click();
}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Select this theme')]")).click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// page2
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.tagName("html")));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='step_wrapper']/form//div[contains(text(),'" + papertype + "')]")).click();
// String selectpapertype1 ="//button[contains(text(),'Select:"+papertype+"')]";

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='step_wrapper']/form//button[contains(text(),'Select:" + papertype + "')]"))).perform();
```

Comment: As you said on 2nd page you are not able to operate the thing. Is your 2nd page is open by 1st one if then many be first you need to switch to respective page and then on the respective frame

Comment: so you mean to say i have to switch to the same frame again and again for the navigated pages? well i had tried doing the same thing, i had rechecked for all the xpath too still webdriver is not able to identify the element, since the description above the iframe#mainFrame is different on different pages i am not able to locate the element. does those descriptions mean the frames are also different

Comment: did you try to use wait?.. If element no found it's also may happen because at loading(navigation to page) time it may be not yet ready. can you please share the code too

Comment: code updated above in the question description

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.